# TYPO3 Indexed_search set startpage

Tags: search, typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-indexed-search

I have the following page_tree in which both de_ch and de_de have the same language (Its needs to be the same language). When I get the searchresults I get the result from both tree's but i just wanna have the results from the current Pagetree (for example only from de_ch and the subpages from this one).

[The Pagetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HjgG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't get me wrong but I do not recommend using indexed_search. The community still invests time to improve this core extension but to be honest: it is quite slow, the concept has some drawbacks and there are better extensions available. There are some - a little bit more complex - solutions for solr (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/solr/) and for elasticsearch (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mksearch/). But this could be an overhead for your project.

A feasible compromise is ke_search (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ke_search/). This extension is well documented (https://www.typo3-macher.de/en/facetted-search-ke-search/documentation/introduction/ in German and English) and easy to install. In less than 2 hours the whole thing is up and indexing. It should be quite easy to achieve your desired goal. If you have problems with it just ask or register for a TYPO3 Slack account. There is a channel #ext-ke_search where people are happy to assist you.